# Is it possible to use template expressions inside style tags?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

```css
grid-template-areas:
            'votes commentBody commentBody'
            'votes commentBody commentBody'
            'commentBottom commentBottom commentBottom'
            '{replies.length ? 'replies replies replies' : ''}';
```

but this errors out

Is it possible to do so? if not why not and how would I approach this? ( inline styles could work as well I suppose, or I could do something like styled-components )

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible inside the style tag, but using them inline is possible

Comment: I did it using, classes but thanks anyway :)

Comment: an alternative is also using css variables instead, something a touch cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working like this:

There's probably a better way to ensure its spaced correctly than some chained replaces, but here it is.

[The REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0f354a3f9fce4974b7e821a6aecc9488?version=3.44.2)

**stores.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const count = writable(1);
```

**index.js**

```
<script>
    import { count } from './stores.js';

    let maxLength = 3;
    $: header = ('header'.repeat($count) + 'spacer'.repeat(3 - $count))
        .replace(/erhe/g, 'er he')
        .replace(/ersp/g, 'er sp');
</script>

<main style={`grid-template-areas:"${header}""content content content""footer footer footer"`}>
    <header>{$count}</header>
    <div class="spacer" />
    <div class="content">
        <button on:click={() => {if ($count < maxLength) $count++}}>More header</button>
        <button on:click={() => {if ($count > 1) $count--}}>Less header</button>
    </div>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        display: grid;
    }
    header {
        grid-area: header;
        padding: 1rem;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    .content {
        grid-area: content;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: #444;
    }
</style>
```